# Why is covariant derivative a tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, covariance

I am trying to prove that the covariant derivative is a tensor (ie it transforms well under a change of coordinates) but I can't succeed to it.

Here is the definition of the covariant derivative :

$$ \nabla_XV= X^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu} V^{\rho}+V^{\nu}\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\rho})\partial_{\rho}$$

I write then the $\rho$ component :

$$ \nabla_XV^{\rho}= X^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu} V^{\rho}+V^{\nu}\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}) $$

In addition, we have :

$$ \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}=\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial y^K}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial y^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\widetilde{\Gamma}_{K \lambda}^{\sigma}+\frac{\partial^2 y^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\lambda}}$$

What we need to prove is that we have :

$$ \nabla_XV^{\nu}=\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\rho}} \widetilde{\nabla_XV^{\rho}} $$

But I really don't know how we could end up to such a result.

Indeed, if I basically replace everything in base "tilde" (also called $y$ here), I will have the term : $V^{\nu}\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}$ that will give :

$$V^{\nu}\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\rho}=\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\widetilde{V}^{\beta}(\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial y^K}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial y^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\widetilde{\Gamma}_{K \lambda}^{\sigma}+\frac{\partial^2 y^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\lambda}})\\=
\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\widetilde{V}^{\beta} \frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial y^K}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial y^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\widetilde{\Gamma}_{K \lambda}^{\sigma}+\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\widetilde{V}^{\beta}\frac{\partial^2 y^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\lambda}}
$$

And I don't see how the second part of this last equality could be compensated in any way because there are only "+" (and not "-") in all the equations.

And we need it to go out because the $\widetilde{V}^{\beta}$ should be either multiplied by the $\Gamma$ or it should be present as a derivative of itself, which is not the case in this second part of this last equality.

Could you help me to see how this term would vanish ?

Don't hesitate if anything is not clear (I tried to avoid to write too much calculations but to point out the term that from my perspective should vanish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial y^\lambda}\frac{\partial y^\lambda}{\partial x^\nu} = \delta^\rho_\nu$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
0 &= \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial y^\lambda}\frac{\partial y^\lambda}{\partial x^\nu} \right)\\
&= \frac{\partial^2 y^\lambda}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial y^\lambda} + \frac{\partial y^\lambda}{\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial y^\kappa}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial^2 x^\rho}{\partial y^\kappa \partial y^\lambda}
\end{align*}
It follows that we can rewrite the transformation rule for the Christoffel symbols as
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial y^\sigma} \frac{\partial y^\kappa}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial y^\lambda}{\partial x^\nu} \widetilde{\Gamma}^\sigma_{\kappa \lambda} - \frac{\partial y^\lambda}{\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial y^\kappa}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial^2 x^\rho}{\partial y^\kappa \partial y^\lambda}
\end{equation}
This gets you the "negative part" that you'll need to make everything cancel out appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I had an extra term : $\widetilde{X}^{\beta}\widetilde{V}^{\sigma}(\frac{\partial^2 x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\beta} \partial y^{\sigma}}+\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial^2 y^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\beta} \partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\lambda}})$ and your trick shows it cancels. But it is really barely recognizable at first... Do you have a "trick" to easily recognize it is the derivative of what you proposed or you just know it would appear "by experience" ?

Comment: Because I would never have found it without your advise, I am looking for "method" to improve my efficiency in thoose calculations, to be able to recognize things like this.

Comment: One thing that might be helpful: if we define the Jacobian matrix as $J^\mu_\nu = \partial y^\mu/\partial x^\nu$ (and its inverse as $(J^{-1})^\mu_\nu = \partial x^\mu/\partial y^\nu$), then it should be clearer that your extra term involves a derivative of $J$ and a derivative of $J^{-1}$. So that raises the question of how the derivative of a matrix relates to the derivative of its inverse, which (perhaps with the help of e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471825/derivative-of-the-inverse-of-a-matrix) leads to the argument I gave above.

Answer (score -2):

We start from the identity:

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{V}}{\partial Z^S} = \nabla_S V^i \mathbf{Z}_i$$

where $\nabla_S V^i$ is the covariant derivative whose components are: $\nabla_S V^i = \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial Z^S} + V^j \Gamma_{jS}^i$.

For any change of coordinate, we obtain:

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{V}}{\partial Z^{k'}} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{V}}{\partial Z^S}\frac{\partial Z^S}{\partial Z^{k'}} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{V}}{\partial Z^S}}_{\nabla_S V^i \mathbf{Z}_i} J_{k'}^S = (\nabla_S V^i \mathbf{Z}_i) J_{k'}^S = \underbrace{\nabla_S V^i J_{k'}^S J_i^{i'}}_{\nabla_{k'}V^{i'}} \mathbf{Z}_{i'} = \nabla_{k'}V^{i'}\mathbf{Z}_{i'}$$

This is my attempt to prove in the easier way that the covariant derivative is a tensor. With capital J I intended to represent the jacobian; with the primed indices I mean the new coordinate set and with the unprimed the original one.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post images of text or mathematics, which break our search function. You can use MathJax, a LaTeX-like language, to display your mathematics natively; [here is some guidance](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).